# Flask bcrypt.check_password_hash() always returns False, can't narrow in on my mistake

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

While trying to write a login functionality in flask, I wanted to try 'bcrypt' flask extensio. When I use_bcrypt.check_password_hash()_ method to compare user form input password against that users saved password in the db, it always returns false.

Here is the code I use to generate passwords:

```
    hashPwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash('form.password.data')
```

Here is the code I use to check the candidate password against the saved one:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()

    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
        login_user(user, remember=form.rememberMe.data)
```

If I do `User.query.get(1).password` in python shell, the password is in format:

```
u'$2b$12$JOXUftWBbn/egABOkAYNwezGKfh6GzIHOofUnvx73AiSOfoNWEGFC'
```

When I run the same query in code, the password is:

```
$2b$12$JOXUftWBbn/egABOkAYNwezGKfh6GzIHOofUnvx73AiSOfoNWEGFC
```

The **u'** in the first pw is the only difference and that might be the issue cause, but I dont know what it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to check against the hashed value of the password, not the plain text password as entered by the user.

Comment: also I see there are invalid quotes 'form.password.data' , you like this will encrypt the string 'form.password.data' not the value of form.password

Answer (score 3):

From http://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash('hunter2')
bcrypt.check_password_hash(pw_hash, 'hunter2') # returns True
```

The reverse function needs to check the hash against the password, in your case
user.password should actually be hashPwd

```
if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(hashPwd, form.password.data):
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri. It's not really clear from the code I pasted, but hashPwd is a class method in my 'register' class and I can't use it in my check, which is a login class method.

Comment: Are you using python3? From the same documentation you might have to do bcrypt.generate_password_hash(‘hunter2’).decode(‘utf-8’)
on the hash

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.1

Comment: hashPwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash('form.password.data')

is that line supposed to hash the password as password = "form.password.data" I thought you might be using it as an example but maybe you just meant to say

hashPwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data)

Comment: That was it. I didn't even noticed I sent in form.password.data as a string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the quotation marks in ('form.password.data')

write as hashPwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data)