# Bcrypt.check_password_hash() not working in FLASK

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, bcrypt, flask-restful

I was writing the backend logic for Login in FLASK ,but flask_bcrypt was not able to verify my saved password hash. I am using an API to interact with my MONGODB database.Can anyone help.

CODE SNIPPET FOR LOGIN:

```
@admin.route("/admin",methods=['POST','GET'])
def admin_login():
    form=LoginForm()
    if session.get("ID",None) is not None:
        return "ALREADY LOGGED IN"
    elif form.validate_on_submit():
        username=form.username.data
        password=form.password.data
        url="http://localhost:9999/run-model/admin-view/{}"
        req=requests.get(url.format(form.username.data)).json()
        #return req.text
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(req['result'][0]["password"],form.password.data):
            session['ID']=username
            return "OK"
        flash('username or password is incorrect','danger')
    return render_template('admin-login.html',form=form)
```

CODE SNIPPET FOR THE API:

```
@app.route('/admin-view/<user>',methods=['GET'])
def admin_view_dynamic(user):
    admin=const.mydb.admin_credentials    #DATABASE CREDS
    output=admin.find_one({"username":user})
    result=[]
    if output:
        result.append({"username":output["username"],"password":output["password"]})
        status_response="Success"
    else:
        status_response="Failure"
    return jsonify({"status":status_response,"result":result})
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the login is not working despite providing correct password. Bcrypt.check_password_hash()  returns False everytime.

Comment: Did you initialise flask_bcrypt

Comment: Make sure that your variables are right passing to `bcrypt.check_password_hash()`. Same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991261/flask-bcrypt-check-password-hash-always-returns-false-cant-narrow-in-on-my-m

Comment: I figured it out the decode('utf-8') specified in the API code created the problem in the Backend . check_password_hash () was decoding it in bytes format but the hash was to be decoded with utf-8